# A quick introduction to modern algebraic varieties.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, reference-request

I am a math student and I know the basics of algebra and algebraic topology. However, I was tasked to read this paper: The Grassmannian of affine subspaces(https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.10883.pdf) which shows that the affine grassmanian may be viewed as a

[image]

Are there texts that I can read to help me understand these terminologies and definition (for each mathematical area) in a concise manner? I am having trouble trying to understand all definitions they use. Currently, I am just reading up bits and pieces of information here and there from places like wikipedia but I feel that it isn't helping much. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for references that contain these definitions or do you want an actual explanation for each definition in the answer? For the former, people might be able to point to specific sections of references in each subject, and you could add the "reference-request" tag to specify that. For the latter, the answer might get quite long to the point that it's a tad unrealistic to expect a high quality and concise explanation that covers everything.

Comment: Also, glancing at the table of contents and skimming some pages of the paper you linked, it seems that definitions of some of these terms are already contained in the paper. Perhaps it would be more efficient to ask about the ones that aren't covered, or ones that you don't understand after reading it.

Comment: Thanks. In particular I find it hard to understand the algebraic geometry topics and definitions i.e. varieties and fiber bundles. Any references for that?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not particularly qualified to talk about algebraic geometry stuff, but for fiber bundles, which I consider more of a differential geometry thing, I'd say John Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* contains a pretty nice introduction to vector bundles in chapter 10, which mentions fiber bundles towards the end of the chapter, though I suppose the text is not necessarily the most concise.

Comment: Also, you could also check out Milnor & Stasheff's *Characteristic Classes*, specifically chapter 2, which introduces vector bundles, and chapter 5, which defines Grassmannians, explains their relations to Stiefel manifolds, and shows how they are classifying spaces (called universal bundles by M&S).

Comment: Though upon closer reading of the paper, I just now notice that they are talking about $\operatorname{Graff}(k, n)$, the set of affine subspaces instead of linear subspaces, so the sources above won't apply exactly to this paper. However, since it's probably a close enough analogy, in case you are not very familiar with Grassmannians of linear subspaces, reading up about them will probably still help.

Comment: I'm not sure you can just understand algebraic geometry out of nowhere. Perhaps look up references for elementary algebraic geometry (there are some posts on MSE), as I assume you will not learn scheme theory in just the matter of a few weeks.